# Open and Receive values from a bat to exe with C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a C# console app to do some proccess. I want to open my demo.exe and send some parameters from a .BAT file to that cosole.

I know the .bat should be something like:

```
demo.exe -a cclock -cc 1306 -mc 1750
```

But, I don't have any idea to make my .exe to get the parameters I'm sending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing command-line arguments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653563/passing-command-line-arguments-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get command line parameters and put them into variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661047/how-to-get-command-line-parameters-and-put-them-into-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the arguments to Main method helps.

In an standard C# program entry method is like,

```
static int Main(string[] args)
```

Here args[] is the array of arguments passed to your executable via command line.
So in your example,

```
demo.exe -a cclock -cc 1306 -mc 1750
```

args is a string array containing following,

```
{"-a", "cclock", "-cc", "1306", "-mc", "1750"}
```

You can retrieve these value in this manner,

```
args[0]  = "-a"
args[1] = "cclock"
args[2]= "-cc" ...... and so on
```

You can use these value for the rest of your code.

Remember that whatever values you pass are broken into separate string values on each occurrence of white-space. Also whatever value you pass will be taken as string. So you have to do your own validation and parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Your application's `Main` method (typically in `Program.cs`) can accept a parameter `string[] args`, which you can access to get the command line parameters used to launch your app. Alternatively, you can also use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` anywhere in the application to do the same thing.